# `stmt` vs `functools.partial` for `timeit.Timer`

Tags: python, performance, time, timeit

I've read that `functools.partial(fn, *args, **kw)` saves overhead compared to `lambda: fn(*args, **kw)`. But is it also advantageous over `stmt`  + `globals`?

```py
timeit.Timer(partial(fn, *args, **kw)).repeat(200, 5)
```

vs

```py
timeit.Timer(stmt='fn(*args, **kw)', 
             globals={'fn': fn, 'args': args, 'kw': kw})
```

or even, though [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) suggest they're interchangeable,

```py
timeit.Timer(stmt='fn(*args, **kw)', 
             globals={'args': args, 'kw': kw},
             setup='from __main__ import fn')
```

I've not found much material on this. For what order of duration of `fn` (e.g. milliseconds) does it make a non-negligible difference? Are they all interchangeable past a certain order, including for parallel (*not* Python-multiprocessing, just multi-core math by e.g. `numpy`) and (optional question) [GPU](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/benchmark.html) benchmarking? Besides using the command line, is any one generally preferred?

---

#### A use case

For reference: a costly `def setup`, then we bench inside `def main` over several configurations. It doesn't concern "micro-benchmarking", e.g. `x += 1`, but stuff that takes on order of milliseconds.

Here's a dummy self-contained example [(try live)](https://replit.com/@OverLordGoldDra/BarrenNavyFormula#main.py); answers are free to invoke other cases. I've since edited it to put it on order of `us` (by changing `x`'s size) - here's for `partial` vs "long form":

- **Very fast CPU**: `1.61us` vs `1.67us` (i7-13700HX)
- **Very slow CPU**: `3.93us` vs `3.92us` (replit's)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
from timeit import Timer
from functools import partial

USE_PARTIAL = 1

#%% Timer, setup, target function --------------------------------------------
def setup():
    k_bool = False
    objs_all = []
    for j_bool in (False, True):
        x = [[[np.random.randn(1, 1) for _ in range(1)] for _ in range(1)]
             for _ in range(1)]
        fkw = dict(j_bool=j_bool)
        objs_all.append((x, fkw))
    return objs_all, k_bool

def my_func(x, i_bool, j_bool=False, k_bool=True):
    # bools, floops, appends
    x_notcopy = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if i + 1 % 2:
            i_bool = not i_bool
        x_notcopy.append([])

        for j in range(len(x[0])):
            if j + 1 % 2:
                j_bool = not j_bool
            x_notcopy[-1].append([])

            for k in range(len(x[0][0])):
                if k + 1 % 2:
                    k_bool = not k_bool

                x_notcopy[-1][-1].extend(x[i][j][k])

    # array ops
    out = np.array(x_notcopy)
    return out

#%% Bench funcs --------------------------------------------------------------
def main(objs_all, k_bool):
    total = 0
    n_iters = 100
    n_repeats = 10000
    for objs in objs_all:
        x, fkw = objs
        for i_bool in (False, True):
            for negate_k_bool in (False, True):
                if negate_k_bool:
                    k_bool = not k_bool

                if USE_PARTIAL:
                    fn_partial = partial(my_func,
                                         x, i_bool, k_bool=k_bool, **fkw)
                    total += min(Timer(fn_partial).repeat(n_repeats, n_iters)
                                 ) / n_iters
                else:
                    total += min(Timer(
                        'my_func(x, i_bool, k_bool=k_bool, **fkw)',
                        globals={'x': x, 'i_bool': i_bool, 'k_bool': k_bool,
                                 'fkw': fkw},
                        setup='from __main__ import my_func'
                        ).repeat(n_repeats, n_iters)) / n_iters

    print(total / 8)  # 8 is total number of loops

#%% Execute ------------------------------------------------------------------
args = setup()
main(*args)
```

Comment: If your benchmarked code takes tens of milliseconds, none of this should matter in any way.

Comment: Good to know. I'm often concerned with `ms` and `100us` also, but generally I wonder whether all this stuff is only for micro-ops.

Comment: I mean, if you're interested in the difference between these, why not timeit these timeits?

Comment: I can't do that every time, and results of one case may not generalize or inform of caveats.